# Zeros of polynomial on the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the exercise #9 p.123 in Conway's book. Function of one complex variable.

The problem is :
If $p(z) = z^n + a_1 z^{n-1} +\cdots+a_n$ and $|p(z)| < 1$ for $|z| = 1.$
Show that $p$ has a zero on $|z| = 1$

Thanks in any advance.

Comment: What do you mean you proved $p$ has a unique solution?  Showing $p(z)=0$ has a solution on the unit circle is what the question is.

Comment: So you mean they have no connection? Zeros in the circle and zeros on the circle.

Comment: I thought that those must be somewhat related. May be I was wrong though

Comment: Could Roche's theorem be of use?

Comment: I've tried all night yesterday. But it does not works... please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Rouché's theorem, if $|p(z)|<|z^n|$ on the unit circle then
$z^n$ and $z^n-p(z)$ have the same number  of zeros (counted with multiplicities) in the unit disk. But $z^n-p(z)$ has degree at most $n-1$.

As there is no such $p$ any statement about $p$ would be correct.

Comment: So why this implies the existence of zero "on" that circle?

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks for your answer! Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

Since on the circle, $|z^n|=1$ and $|p(z)| < 1$, we must have $(p(z)-z^n)$ nonzero, and $\arg(p(z)-z^n)$ must be in the interval of length $\pi$ opposite to $\arg(z^n)$.

$\arg(p(z)-z^n)$ is within $\pi/2$ of $\arg(-z^n)$.

This is enough to show that the winding number around $0$ of $p(z)-z^n$ is the same as $-z^n$'s, which is $n$. This implies that $p(z)-z^n$ has $n$ zeroes inside the circle.

However, $p(z)-z^n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, so this whole situation is impossible.